# Error Code: 1231. Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'ORACLE'

Tags: sql

I was trying to use this code

`SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI,ORACLE';`

But it returns error

`Error Code: 1231. Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'ORACLE'`

I copied the source code from somewhere else and may not understand every line of codes. Can I know what is the purpose of the above code?  Why does it need to set the sql_mode to ANSI, ORACLE and why is it not working in my query? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your tags state MySQL and and SQL Server, and your question talks about Oracle. What RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: Also note, that mode `ORACLE` was previously supported in MySQL, but was removed in version 8.0.  The purpose of sql_mode is to support different "dialects" of sql. For details see the documentation of your dbms. For mysql for instance https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-sql-modes.html